How to correcly load SVG images on 2 deep level URL's using webpack?
I'm having an issue using webpack in my ReactJS application.
On URL's that there is only a single endpoint such as http://localhost:8000/login my Logo image loads correctly, but if I type an URL that is more than only one deep level, e.g: http://localhost:8000/reset/forgot it doesn't download the SVG and the image doesn't load.
The image tag that loads the image is the same for both URL (It is located on my header so it should load to all pages).
If I inspect the SVG download request, is trying to get the images from http://localhost:8000/reset/assets/Logo_WHT.svg instead of http://localhost:8000/assets/Logo_WHT.svg.
This is my webpack config:
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const os = require("os");


var config = {
  entry: {
    index: "./src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [ 
      {
        resolve: {
          fallback: {
            "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),          // install 'stream-http'
            "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),   // install 'https-browserify'
            "vm": require.resolve("vm-browserify"),         // install 'os-browserify'
            "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"), // install 'vm-browserify'
            "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/"),            // install 'buffer'
            "url": false,
            "constants": false,
          }
        }
      },     
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              ["@babel/preset-env", {              
                targets: [
                  "last 2 versions",
                  "ie 11",
                  "not dead",
                  "> 0.5%"
                ]
              }],
              "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/, 
        type: "asset/resource"
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$|\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
};

Originally I was using file-loader to load files, but on webpack 5.x.x that's not recommended anymore, so I changed to the asset/resource (as it says on the documentation).
I'm expecting to load all files from the root folder "assets"
